# Apache config file for alias

Tags: apache, owncloud

I am trying to learn a little about apache configuration.
I am running a web based dropbox type solution called owncloud.

The installer configures apache for you and places owncloud in its own sub directory (www.yourdomain.com/owncloud).

I have succesfully moved over all the files and located in the owncloud.conf file where this configuration is.

```
Alias /owncloud /var/www/owncloud/html/"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All

<IfModule mod_dav.c>
  Dav off
</IfModule>

SetEnv HOME /var/www/html
SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html


 </Directory>

 <Directory "/var/www/html/owncloud/data/">
```

As you can see the alias calls out /owncloud.
I see I have to change all the lines from

```
  /var/www/owncloud/html/"
```

to

```
 /var/www/html/"
```

However what do I change

```
      Alias /owncloud
```

to?

I tried

```
 Alias /
```

But that made the server fail?

Answer (score 0):

`/var/www/html` is the standard `/` directory of Apache, so you don't need `Alias`, if you move your files there. Most likely there will be a duplicate Directory section for `/var/www/html` in httpd.conf too, which you accidentally override now.